# A wordsearch for today

Tags: no-computers, seasonal, word-search, humor

Sixteen 4-letter words have been concealed in the grid below, as well as one word that is much larger.

**Can you find all seventeen words?**

[image: Wordsearch grid]

<sub>Text version of the wordsearch (for copy-paste purposes):</sub>

```
JBUGEHLPOVCRAAWFGPEUMIZDTO
PAXYBDTGIIOPFWSSCOQPEFFLYS
EAEGKLKOCXNMAGLZAATAIIADLF
SVFWGWPAZJQBAYUURISWSIZREA
JUHGUUTROXEYRPYHJOTFUSLOQU
MAWAWDSVWIDROWZWORDXDROWFP
QBOIARDVORRFJOAOKUZJREZOPO
EKRSIOAARZOUJRFRLBCAOJQRXU
APDROWORDPWORDDDIOXVWORDKG
ORPOABUKKTJAAGVWOOWLBEFNML
TTANMABVSIEEESTVIXHRIMKRAJ
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turns out…

> This is a literal **WORD SEARCH!!**
>
>  [image]
>
> As 16 ‘word’s make up a much larger ‘word’!
>
> Hence the word search being for today, April fools!

Comment: You beat me to it, good job!

Comment: Well done :) You're clearly no April fool!

Comment: rot13(Jn-jn-jn Jbeq, jbeq, jbeq.  Jbeq vf gur jbeq.  Jbeq, jbeq, jbeq.  Jbeq vf gur jbeq.)

Comment: rot13(`V'z abg fher vs vg'f va nal qvpgvbanevrf, fvapr vg pbzrf sebz gur jbeyq bs snagnfl naq ebyrcynl, ohg "qebj" vf nyfb n jbeq. :Q`)